# How to use the lambda function in GremlinPython?

Tags: python, lambda, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

How to use the lambda function in GremlinPython?

To do a case-insensitive search, I tried the following code,

```
g.V().filter(lambda: "x -> x.get().value('title') == 'open', 'gremlin-groovy'").toList()
```

but, got the following error,

```
E             File "<string>", line 1
E               lambda x -> x.get().value('title') == 'open', 'gremlin-groovy'
E                         ^
E 

      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The exception message you're getting suggest different code than you show above. The error code doesn't have the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Gremlin Server with an empty TinkerGraph, I was able to get it to work. However, I was not initially able to get it to work when `gremlin-groovy` was explicitly specified. See the "UPDATED" section for an explanation of that issue.

```py
>>> g.addV('test').property('p','Hello').next()
v[4]
>>> g.V().map(lambda: 'x->x.get().values("p")[0]=="hello"').next()
False
>>> g.V().map(lambda: 'x->x.get().values("p")[0]=="Hello"').next()
True
```

or, using `value` instead of `values`

```py
>>> g.V().map(lambda: 'x->x.get().value("p")=="hello"').next()
False
>>> g.V().map(lambda: 'x->x.get().value("p")=="Hello"').next()
True
```

and ignoring case

```py
>>> g.V().map(lambda: 'x->x.get().value("p").toUpperCase()=="HELLO"').next()
True
```

A couple of points to note:

1. The "lambda" uses the Groovy syntax to I had to use `toUpperCase` rather than the Python `upper`.
2. In general it is recommended to avoid using lambdas/closures as they are not supported by all TinkerPop enabled databases.

**UPDATED**

To get the lambda to work, with the `gremlin-groovy` present, requires that an extra pair of parenthesis be used. This is essentially creating a tuple of the lambda and the script language hint.

```py
>>> g.V().map(lambda: ('x->x.get().value("p").toUpperCase()=="HELLO"','gremlin-groovy')).next()
True
```

Comment: is there any alternative for a case-insensitive search? Lambda is not supported in AWS Neptune.

Comment: Ah OK - I did not see Amazon-Neptune in the tags. Neptune supports integration with Elastic/Open Search. That is likely the way to go for now. Once Neptune moves up to TinkerPop 3.6 the new `TextP.regex` will be available that can help with some of these searches.